# Connect to user-defined network in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I imagine this question has been asked a bunch, but can't seem to find a concise answer...

I have the following Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  foo-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  foo-pg-db:
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./bootstrap/pg:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
    networks:
      - foo-network
```

This runs and I'm able to connect to it from my app code with the following URL: "postgres://admin@foo-pg-db/foo", but if I'm trying to connect to this from my Mac, what is the "host" portion of the connection URL? It's not localhost is it?

Comment: From outside of Docker you use the published `ports:`.  There's some discussion in the Docker [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) documentation and the [Docker Desktop for Mac Networking](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#port-mapping) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For me similar thing happened with MySQL container that "localhost" was not identified as valid address for docker container address and using "127.0.0.1" worked.

> 127.0.0.1 is default address in linux systems, check your **hosts** file for exact address used by your os

Also, your network has nothing to do with it because you are directly using ports variable :-

```
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

This actually binds your container port to host post.

```
<host_port> : <container_port>
```